# PHP/PDO how reuse connection started in a class to resolve "There is no active transaction" error

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I have one class that encapsulate PDO defined as that example:

```
class db{
       private $conn=null;

       function __construct(){
          getConn();
       }

       function getConn(){
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", 'username', 'password'); 
       }

    }
```

I want reuse same db connection between different class instances so i can use transaction during complex operation like example:

```
function getDataFromAnotherTable(){
 $db = new dbClass;
 $data = execute('select * from table2');
 return $data;
}

//main code start here...
$db = new db; //here i will instantiate class defined above
$db->beginTrans();
$db->execute(insert into table1);

//here transaction still active
$data = getDataFromAnotherTable()

//now transaction has been closed by previous call!

$db->execute('insert into table1');

 //here i receive "There is no active transaction" error because transaction is closed inside
 // getDataFromAnotherTable()
 $db->endTransaction();
```

i want change my class like:

```
       function __construct(){
         if(empty($this->conn){             
          getConn();
         }             
        }
```

So if a connection already exists, will be reused and no new connection will be created.
I've already tried this method but every instance of class obtain new connection so i can't reuse same connection to maintain my transaction over different classes and functions.

Please remember that this is only a simplified example! my situation is really more complex so i can't do a single insert statement using something like:

```
select x from table1 insert into table2
```

Thank you in advance for any support!

Comment: there is not much point in such incapsulation.

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment, but as i stated in my post, this is only a real simplified example. My DB class is not used only for connection but cover a lot of other problems. So, you need more info to help me or you think that is impossible to reach my goal?

Comment: I am afraid it is solving mainly non-existent problems, like most of PHP codes do

Comment: Your problem has extremely simple solution. Just start your database connection only ONCE and then use it all the way around.  That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make $conn a static variable...

```
class myClass
{
    private $conn = NULL;

    function __construct()
    {
        static $nDB = false;

        if ($nDB === false)
        {
            echo "INIT DB\n";
            $nDB = true;
        }

        $this->conn = $nDB;
    }
}

class myOne
{
    private $oDB = NULL;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->oDB = new myClass();
    }
}

class myTwo
{
    private $oDB = NULL;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->oDB = new myClass();
    }

}

$f1 = new myOne();
$f2 = new myTwo();
```

Should net you only one echo of

```
INIT DB
```

This is because the $conn is shared among all versions of myClass that are loaded.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you suggestion, but in effect my problem is even that i must call the constructor between different classes with a common parent but every classes call the db class individually

Comment: I don't think that is an issue. Changing my answer to clarify. Given the change -- you could have two different classes, both create a property of "myClass" and the connections that "myClass" use would be shared. Allowing each of the objects (myOne, myTwo) to access their own private pointer to $this->oDB (or whatever you want to call it) -- yet they all use the same connection to your database.

Comment: You are a Genius :) Thank you very much! all work fabulously thank you very much! this is the perfect solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options basically.

First, if you have OOP exclusively all over the place, you have to pass PDO connection as a class property.

```
// having no class at hand I am passing $db into function as well
function getDataFromAnotherTable($db){
 $data = $db->execute('select * from table2');
 return $data;
}
$db = new db; //here i will instantiate class defined above
$db->beginTransaction();
$db->execute(insert into table1);
$data = getDataFromAnotherTable($db);
$db->execute('insert into table1');
$db->commit();
```

Second, you are mainly using old plain procedural style, then singleton would be the best answer. You'll only have to change -> to :: and get rid of this  `new dbClass;` stuff:

```
function getDataFromAnotherTable(){
    return DB::query('select * from table2')->fetchAll();
}

DB::beginTransaction();
DB::prepare("insert into table1 VALUES(?,?)")->execute([1,2]);
$data = getDataFromAnotherTable()
DB::prepare("insert into table1 VALUES(?,?)")->execute([3,4]);
DB::commit();
```